# Projections of standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projection

Suppose that we are given the standard basis $e_1,\ldots, e_n$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n$ is odd.
Is there an orthogonal projection $P$ to two dimensional subspace and a positive integer $k$ such that $Pe_i=u$ for $1\leq i\leq k$ and $Pe_j=v$ for $k+1\leq j\leq n$ where $u,v$ are orthogonal and have the same length?

Comment: Your question should include context and your own efforts to approach the problem. Have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

When $k\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$, the image of the proposed linear map would be $\operatorname{span}(u,v)$. Let's find the kernel. For $x=\lambda_1 e_1+\dots+\lambda_n e_n$ we have
$$
Px = (\lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_k) u + (\lambda_{k+1}+\dots+\lambda_n)v,
$$
so that $Px=0$ is equivalent to $\lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_k=0$ and $\lambda_{k+1}+\dots+\lambda_n=0$, since $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent. We conclude that
$$
\ker(P) = \operatorname{span}(e_i-e_{i+1} : i=1,\dots,k-1,k+1,\dots,n-1).
$$
The orthogonal complement of $\ker(P)$ consists of all vectors of the form
$$
\lambda(e_1+\dots+e_k)+\mu(e_{k+1}+\dots+e_n),
$$
so in order for kernel and image to be orthgonal, $u$ and $v$ have to be of this form. Let $u$ be given by choosing $\lambda_u, \mu_u$ and $v$ by choosing $\lambda_v,\mu_v$ in the expression above. In order for $P$ to be a projection, we need to have
\begin{align*}
u &= Pu = k\lambda_u u + (n-k)\mu_u v, \\
v &= Pv = k\lambda_v u + (n-k)\mu_v v.
\end{align*}
Since $u,v$ are linearly independent, this uniquely determines $u$ and $v$ as
\begin{align*}
u &=\frac 1 k (e_1+\dots+e_k), \\
v &=\frac 1 {n-k} (e_{k+1}+\dots+e_k).
\end{align*}
Those vectors are in fact orthogonal, but their square norms are $\frac 1 k$ and $\frac 1 {n-k}$ respectively, so they can only have the same length when $n=2k$.

Hence, there is no such projection when $n$ is odd.

Comment: Thanks, but is that not only for coordinate projection?

Comment: @Silbraz I don't understand your question. I never assumed that $P$ is a coordinate projection, nor is the map resulting from the $u$ and $v$ I gave a coordinate projection.

Comment: Ι misunderstood something in your proof. It is fine, I agree.